# Error al publicar Asp.NETCore Web API - 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

Estuve teniendo un problema bastante pesado, instalé mi `WebAPI` en un servidor `IIS` corporativo de mi empresa, y específicamente, cuando intentaba usar un `HTTPMethod` `DELETE` en una aplicación que consume ese `API`, estaba obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://UrlDelApi' from origin 'http://UrlDelSitioWeb' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Primero pensé que podría ser problema del `CORS` en mi aplicación, pero ya lo tenía configurado. La configuración es la siguiente:

***ConfigureServices***

```
public readonly string _MyCors="CorsPolicy";
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //...mucho código antes de esto
            //agregamos el CORS para las peticiones HTTP desde el cliente.
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: _MyCors, builder =>
                {
                   //recordatorio: permitir cualquier header, origen y método no es buena práctica 
                   builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin();
                });
            });
        }
```

**Configure**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        
        /*
         * Permitiremos a CORS que:
         * Permita recibir peticiones de cualquier origen
         * Permitir recibir peticiones para cualquier método
         * Recibir cualquier encabezado en la petición
         */
        app.UseCors(_MyCors);
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

**¿Qué está faltando?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una vez verificando que el error no provenía de la configuración del `CORS`, ya que ahí específicamente dice que le permito cualquier origen, método y `header`, proseguí a seguir investigando. Llegué a [Esta publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854602/asp-net-web-api-405-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed-how) en la que vi que ya hubo problemas similares con esto. El problema lo atribuyen a una característica del `IIS` llamada `WebDav`. En principio la respuesta aceptada, dice que deberías de desactivar esa característica de windows, cosa que para mí, no es posible. navegando más en esa pregunta, encontré esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14465655/8166997):

> No necesitas desinstalar `WebDav`. Agrega a tu `Web.Config` lo siguiente:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Con eso, mi aplicación empezó a funcionar correctamente.

Decidí compartir esto porque a mí me llevó más de 4 horas encontrar una solución, así que espero que, a alguien en algún futuro le pueda servir.
¡Saludos! :D

Comment: Nunca está demás mencionar que no es buena idea tener `builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin();` en los servidores de producción, aún para aplicaciones no expuestas hacia afuera. En Dev está bien, pero Prod tal vez no.

Comment: no es correcto, pero en mi caso particular, a falta de definición de aplicaciones actualmente, lo tengo así jajaja, pero tienes toda la razón